# how to remove pages, categories,archeive in my all pages of website in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

[image]

I am want hide all the page name show in bottom side of product page
This is the problem i m new in wordpress please help me.
Regards,
Saurabh Sharma

Answer (score 0):

**Deleting Pages:**

1. Log into your WordPress Dashboard (www.example.com/wp-admin).
2. Select the 'Pages' tab, in the left hand corner.
3. Scroll over the relevant Page(s) and select delete.
4. This will send the Page to the 'Bin'.  The 'Bin' is like the Recycling Bin on a Windows Desktop.  To completely remove the Page(s), select 'Bin' and then 'Delete Permanently'.

**Deleting Categories:**

1. Head into your WordPress Dashboard (www.example.com/wp-admin).
2. Select the 'Posts' tab on the left hand side.
3. You should then uncover a sub menu, entitled 'Categories'.  Select this.
4. Then remove the relevant 'Categories'.
5. Do note that 'Uncategorized' is the default WordPress Category and cannot be deleted.

**Deleting Archives:**

1. Head into your WordPress Dashboard (www.example.com/wp-admin).
2. Select 'Appearance' and then 'Widgets'.
3. Then remove 'Archives' from the relevant Widget area.

**Deleting the Containers:**

The steps above, shows you how to delete the content.  Despite the content being deleted, you will likely still be left with the assigned containers on the pages.  Containers are the 'boxes' the Theme Author inputs into the page Templates, so that when you add 'Archives, 'Pages' etc within the Widget area, the website knows where to output said content.

With every WordPress theme being structured differently, it is not possible to provide you with specific steps.  With this in mind, you are likely better off asking for some direction from your Theme Author.  If this is not possible, see how you get on with the steps below:

1. Your first task is to download a file uploading piece of software, such as [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/).  This is a free piece of software and allows you to access your web files.  You may need to speak with your Hosting Company, for help with the login credentials etc.
2. Create a Backup of your web files, using Filezilla.  You can do this, by simply downloading your web files from Filezilla and to your desktop.  In the future, you will need to back up, both, your web files and your MySql database.  Simply backing up yuour web files, will suffice for this exercise.
3. Create a [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).  Your Child Theme will be where you implement your own customisations.  If you do not create a Child Theme, and implement your customisations within the Parent Theme, you will lost said customisations when your Theme Author rolls out a Theme update.
4. Using FileZilla, you will need to find where the Template files have been created, within your Parent Theme. This is where there will be Theme based variations.  As a starting point, you want to head to /httpdocs/wp-content/themes/theme-name.  'theme-name' being the actual theme of your WordPress theme.
5. You then need to replicate the Folder hierarchy within your Child Theme.
6. Once this has been achieved, you then need to go into each of the Templates and remove `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` from the template(s).  There may be variations of this, such as `<?php get_sidebar('archives'); ?>` and `<?php get_sidebar('categories'); ?>`.  I would suggest removing one at a time, then refresh your website after each deletion, as to ascertain if the correct entry was removed.

Hope this helps, even if just to get you started off.